# Android 6, how to delete files with a USB OTG connection

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app for our truck drivers: they have a scanner with a SD card and a tablet with Android 6.0, the scanner SD is accessible using a USB OTG cable.
I successfully managed to read the PDF files stored on the SD card and to send them to our company server, but now I'd like to delete them from the SD.

Apparently the SD card, being removable storage is read-only and the best way to gain read-write access would be ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and Intent, but I don't want to force our drivers to select the root of the SD card every time, so I'm trying to understand if I can delete the files without any user input.

I created a custom provider into my Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

and this is my provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

This is my code:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
File fileboh = new File("/storage/" + arraydir[2] + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/" + name);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(),"com.company.appautisti.provider", fileboh);
System.out.println(fileUri);
DocumentFile txtFile2 = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, Uri.parse("content://com.company.appautisti.provider/external_files/"+ arraydir[2] +"/DCIM/100MEDIA/" + name));
txtFile2.delete();
```

I know the real file path is /storage/52AE-5CF8/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0001.PDF and fileUri output is content://com.company.appautisti.provider/external_files/52AE-5CF8/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0001.PDF, but the delete() method is not working, any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want to force our drivers to select the root of the SD card every time" -- they only need to select it once. Use `takePersistableUriPermission()` to retain rights to that document tree. "but the delete() method is not working" -- you do not have permissions to delete arbitrary content on removable storage.

Comment: By "they only need to select it once" what do you mean exactly? Are the rights retained even after device poweroff or if the scanner is removed and connected again? Thanks

Comment: "Are the rights retained even after device poweroff or if the scanner is removed and connected again?" -- they should be retained after the phone/tablet is powered off and on. I hope they are retained after the scanner is removed and connected again, but I cannot guarantee that -- you would have to test that scenario.

Comment: Let the files be put in app specific folder of sd card. There you have all rights. getExternalFilesDirs[1] is ment.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can confirm that I resolved my problem using `takePersistableUriPermission()` and it's working even when the scanner is removed and connected again!